# Exit jquery function triggered by mousedown event

Tags: jquery, html, events, contextmenu

I have a jquery function like so:

```
$(function(){
    $('.viewArea').mousedown(function(event) {
        if(event.which === 3){  // On right click
            pos = ("(" + event.pageX + "," + event.pageY + ")");
            console.log(pos);  // Log the xy coords of click to console
            $.contextMenu("destroy");  // Unregister previous context menu
            $.contextMenu({  // Create new context menu
                selector: '.viewArea',
                callback: function(key, options){
                    var m = "clicked: " + key;
                    window.console && console.log(m);
                },
                items: {
                    "pos":{name:pos,disabled:true}, // have pos in context menu
                    "ci1":{name:"ContextMenu 1"},
                    "ci2":{name:"ContextMenu 2"}
                }
            });
        }
    })
});
```

This function uses the jquery plugin "jQuery contextMenu".

What I want is to be able to right click and have the pos coordinates displayed right in the context menu.  The problem is, after the first context menu is created, immediately creating a second one (right clicking elsewhere) will not display updated coordinates.  Getting out of the first context menu (by left clicking outside, or selecting an option) then opening a new context menu will display the updated coordinates.

A deeper examination of the problem shows that the console isn't logging *anything* if you continually right click opening context menus, when it should be logging the new position.  In other words, it's only detecting the right click once and not going through the function again until a different input has occurred.

I've tried using the .click event instead (and with left clicking) but the same problem occurs.  I've also tried changing the reposition flag in jquery.contextMenu.js to false under the assumption that the context menu just wasn't rebuilding, but that didn't appear to change anything, either.

Any help would be vastly appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle, so we can visualise the problem?

Comment: @Raptus I should've done that originally.. [http://jsfiddle.net/Ruxb7/](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruxb7/).  Also, I have achieved a rather messy solution of altering the javascript file for the context menu by removing the portion of code where the menu is repositioned.  Unfortunately this will cause the context menu to close, then you need to right click again to reopen it.  So it doesn't solve the root problem, but it does keep users from getting incorrect information from the multi-right click problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Author of said plugin here…

I'm not sure what it really is you're trying to achieve there. But to help you into the right direction I've fixed your example to use the `position` function to call an update to your position display.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ruxb7/1/

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not possible.  From inspecting the html on your jsfiddle, you can see that the way contextMenu is implemented, an invisible element is being placed over whichever elements you have bound the contextMenu to (`.viewArea`).  You can verify this yourself by inspecting the overlay element `#context-menu-layer` (using jQuery to search for this element will not work in the jsfiddle, since the output example is inside an iframe.  still, you can manually inspect the 'Elements' tab of the chrome debugger.)

You can also verify this by looking at the [source code](https://github.com/medialize/jQuery-contextMenu/blob/master/src/jquery.contextMenu.js).  Inside the `layerClick` function on line 347 you can see that all events are killed (lines 358-359) by this handler.  The handler is bound to all `mousedown` events on `#context-menu-layer` at line 1189.

I recommend using a different library that will properly fit your needs.

In the meantime, I have filed a [bug](https://github.com/medialize/jQuery-contextMenu/issues/226) for you with the jQuery contextMenu creator / maintainer.